# After selecting file for file input element, focus is not returned to the elements/page

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

After selecting a file, I have to click anywhere on the page before I can interact with the page again.  This is very annoying and I don't want me user's to have to deal with this.  Is there a way to return focus to the page without that first click?

I should note this only happens in IE.

Comment: did u try `onchange` event of the `fileupload`?

Comment: Show some relevant code and tell which version of IE. Inspect what's the `document.activeElement` when that happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't explain it but I think I figured out the cause.  I am on a different computer right now, and the problem doesn't exist here.  The only thing I can come up with is that the computer I was on last night is a Mac running Windows 7 in a VM via coherence mode...  That has to have something to do with it.